# Monitoring files in Powershell and using ArrayList

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell. I would like to add a file path to an ArrayList every time it changes. However, this PowerShell script fails somehow. Any hints what might I be doing wrong?

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\Mydir"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$jobs = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

$changed = Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action {
    $changedFile = $($eventArgs.FullPath)
    $jobs.Add($changedFile)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scope issue. Add the global scope modifier:

```
$global:jobs.Add($changedFile)
```

see about_Scopes for more help.

Comment: Is it possible to give $jobs as a parameter to Changed-action?

Comment: Try the MessageData parameter.